# stop javascript from closing an open collapsed list

Tags: javascript

I have a simple java script below that opens and closes a collapsible list.  In the list are links and when you click on a link which opens a new window, the list collapses.  I would like to keep the list open when clicking such link.

Java Script

```
function dropDown(li) {
var submenu = li.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var x = "de" + li.id;
if (submenu) {
    submenu.style.display = submenu.style.display == "block" ? "" : "block";
}
if (document.getElementById(x).getAttribute('src') == "plus.gif") {
    document.getElementById(x).src = "minus.gif";
} else if (document.getElementById(x).getAttribute('src') == "minus.gif") {
    document.getElementById(x).src = "plus.gif";
}
```

}

My HTML

```
<ul class="doclist">
<li onClick="dropDown(this);" id="1"> <a><image src="plus.gif" width="10" id="de1">&nbsp;<b>My Reports</b></a>

    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <A HREF="report1.pdf" TARGET="new"><B>Report 1</B></A></li>      
   </ul>
 </li>
 <P>
 <li onClick="dropDown(this);" id="2">
  <a><image src="plus.gif" width="10" id="de2">&nbsp;<b>Other Reports</b></a>

            <ul>
                <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <A HREF="report20.pdf" TARGET="new"><B>Report 20</B></A></li>
    <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="report21.pdf" TARGET="new"><B>Report 21</B></A></li>
   </ul>
 </li>  
</ul>
```

My CSS

```
ul.doclist li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

example on jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cb49747/ka13kyee/

Comment: You problem seem to be related to event bubbling (cancel that, google is your friend). I guess there is plenty of options for those kind of menus. Using a ready one will not be better?

Comment: You should post the relevant CSS also. If you could put all that in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) even better.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cb49747/ka13kyee/

Comment: Seems I cant add multiple lines in comments.  I have created a working model on jsfiddle i could not get jsfiddle to read the javascript though so I just added it to the html portion.  if you click on one of the report links you will see it closes the list.

Comment: The function you defined in your fiddle doesn't work because it was set to be executed in an `onLoad` handler and your function was defined in that scope then unavailable to your inline event handlers, to quickly make it work you just need to change the combo in the left-top that says "onLoad" to "No wrap - in <head>". It is good to know you solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer was a to add this to each link in my lists.

```
onClick="event.stopPropagation();"
```

so the links would now look like this.

```
<A HREF="report20.pdf" TARGET="new" onClick="event.stopPropagation();"><B>Report 20</B></A>
```

Thanks to prusse who got me on the right track with the event bubbling.  Another note is that this will only work with W3C compliant browsers.  Another option would be to use this instead.

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
```

but be advised that has not been tested.